# LazyLoading prevents RestController from returning the correct values

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I think Hibernate's lazy loading may be preventing my Controller from returning the appropriate response.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/shifts")
public class ShiftController {
    private ShiftService shiftService;

    @Autowired
    public ShiftController(ShiftService shiftService) {
        this.shiftService = shiftService;
    }

    @GetMapping("")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('ADMIN','SUPERVISOR')")
    Collection<Shift> getShifts() {
        return shiftService.fetchAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('ADMIN','SUPERVISOR')")
    ResponseEntity<Shift> getOneShift(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        Shift shift = shiftService.fetchOne(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(shift, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Shift Class

```
@Entity
public class Shift {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "SHIFT_ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "START", nullable = false)
    private OffsetDateTime start;

    @Column(name = "END", nullable = false)
    private OffsetDateTime end;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", nullable = false)
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "TASK_ID", nullable = false)
    private Task task;
}
```

When running my test without debugging I get the following response (Body is NULL).

```
MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 200
    Error message = null
          Headers = {Content-Type=[application/json;charset=UTF-8], X-Content-Type-Options=[nosniff], X-XSS-Protection=[1; mode=block], Cache-Control=[no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate], Pragma=[no-cache], Expires=[0], X-Frame-Options=[DENY]}
     Content type = application/json;charset=UTF-8
             Body = null
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
```

When I add a breakpoint at the line `Shift shift = shiftService.fetchOne(id);` in the `ShiftController`,step-over, then resume, I get the response I want (Body Exists).

```
MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 200
    Error message = null
          Headers = {Content-Type=[application/json;charset=UTF-8], X-Content-Type-Options=[nosniff], X-XSS-Protection=[1; mode=block], Cache-Control=[no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate], Pragma=[no-cache], Expires=[0], X-Frame-Options=[DENY]}
     Content type = application/json;charset=UTF-8
             Body = {"id":2,"start":"2018-03-22T17:17:57.387-07:00","end":"2018-03-22T17:17:57.389-07:00","user":{"id":1,"username":"testuser","email":null,"role":"STUDENT"},"task":{"id":1,"name":"CLEANUP"}}
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
```

Some Googling leads me to believe that the issues stems from Hibernate's Lazy Loading. Whats the fix for this?

EDIT: Forgot to add that the `shiftService.fetchOne()` method just wraps the `JpaRepository's getOne()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be the culprit of your problem.

> Forgot to add that the shiftService.fetchOne() method just wraps the
>   JpaRepository's getOne() method.

The getOne method returns only the reference from **DB (lazy loading)**. So basically you are outside of the transaction (the Transactional you have been declared in service class is not considered), and hence the slow response time in lazy loading.

Instead of `getOne()`, you should use `findOne()` JPA API in your `shiftService.fetchOne()` implementation

Look at the API documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.html)